# Error message when trying to make deploy of CommCare app "whoops, that didn't go through. Reload the page and click "Make New Version"

Tags: commcare

I'm trying to make a new build of a CommCare application and I received the error message "whoops, that didn't go through. Reload the page and click make a new version." I tried to follow those exact directions but I was able to reproduce this message 4 times. I've recently deleted a module in CommCare and I assume this is related. Can someone  help me figure out what is causing this error?

Comment: CommCare is a web based application building platform that does not require any coding to build data collection apps -- it seems more appropriate to ask via commcare tag on web apps because I'm not writing any lines of code, rather I'm using the "form builder" web app version of CommCare. I assume if I'm not contributing to the CommCare code base or writing in a coding language called CommCare, then I should be posting here?

Comment: Hi Claire.  I had a comment conversation with Ben on another post.  We've been hemming and hawing about the best place for questions on the product.  The product is completely new to me, so when I read "build," I thought it was a code issue rather than one dealing with the interface.  We're going to play it by ear, but I will reopen this one for the time being based on the information you have provided.

Comment: Some of the discussion from when the tag was first proposed: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4100/adding-commcare-tag-to-web-applications.  Feel free to comment or weigh in or ask a fresh discussion question on Meta regarding all of these issues.

Comment: Thank you! Looking forward to being part of this ongoing discussion. So far being able to ask these questions here has been incredibly helpful for my usage of the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"whoops, that didn't go through..." is the default blanket error message that CommCare HQ will generate when something went wrong and it wasn't able to tell you what. Generally in this situation the best option is to "report an issue" so that the platform developers can figure out what's going on and introduce a better error message for future occurrences of the problem.

If you are blocked, I would recommend using the "revert" feature to go back to a previous working version of the application, recognizing that this will cause some of your recent work to be lost.